# Elixir, using function from another module

Tags: function, elixir

I am extremely new to the programming and to the elixir. So I am very exited to learn as much as I can. But I've got a problem. I looking the way how to use my functions in another module. I am building the web-server which stores the key-value maps in the memory. To keep the maps temporary I've decided to use Agent. Here is the part of my code:

```
defmodule Storage do
  use Agent

  def start_link do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: :tmp_storage)
  end

  def set(key, value) do
    Agent.update(:tmp_storage, fn map -> Map.put_new(map, key, value) end)
  end

  def get(key) do
    Agent.get(:tmp_storage, fn map -> Map.get(map, key) end)
  end
end
```

So I'm trying to put this functions to the routes of the web server:

```
defmodule Storage_router do
  use Plug.Router
  use Plug.Debugger
  require Logger
  plug(Plug.Logger, log: :debug)
  plug(:match)
  plug(:dispatch)

  post "/storage/set" do
    with {:ok, _} <- Storage.set(key, value) do
      send_resp(conn, 200, "getting the value")
    else
      _ ->
        send_resp(conn, 404, "nothing")
    end
  end
end
```

And I receive:

> warning: variable "key" does not exist and is being expanded to "key()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
> lib/storage_route.ex:12
>
> warning: variable "value" does not exist and is being expanded to "value()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
> lib/storage_route.ex:12

looking for any suggestions\help

Comment: I made a change to mix.exs with an explanation for the change below the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am extremly new to the programming and to the elixir.

I do not think it is wise to begin learning programming with elixir. I would start with python or ruby, and then after a year or two then I would try elixir.

The first thing you need to learn is how to post code.  Search google for how to post code on stackoverflow.  Then, you have to get your indenting all lined up.  Are you using a computer programming text editor?  If not, then you have to get one.  There are many free ones.  I use vim, which comes installed on Unix like computers.  You can learn how to use vim by typing `vimtutor` in a terminal window.

Next, you have a syntax error in your code:

```
 Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: :tmp_storage
    end)
```

That should be:

```
 Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: :tmp_storage)
```

The warning you got is because your code tries to do the equivalent of:

```
def show do
   IO.puts x
end
```

Elixir and anyone else reading that code would ask, "What the heck is x?"  The variable x is never assigned a value anywhere, and therefore the variable x does not exist, and you cannot output something that is non-existent.  You do the same thing here:

```
   with {:ok, _} <- Storage.set(key, value) do
     send_resp(conn, 200, "getting the value")
   else
     _->
      send_resp(conn, 404, "nothing")
   end
```

You call the function:

```
Storage.set(key, value)
```

but the variables `key` and `value` were never assigned a value, and elixir (and anyone else reading that code) wonders, "What the heck are key and value?"

This is the way functions work:

b.ex:

```
defmodule MyFuncs do
  def show(x, y) do
    IO.puts x
    IO.puts y
  end
end

defmodule MyWeb do
  def go do
    height = 10
    width = 20

    MyFuncs.show(height, width)
  end
end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex b.ex
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> MyWeb.go
10
20
:ok
iex(2)>
```

So, in your code you need to write something like this:

```
post "/storage/set" do
  key = "hello"
  value = 10

  with {:ok, _} <- Storage.set(key, value) do
    send_resp(conn, 200, "Server saved the key and value.")
  else
    _->
      send_resp(conn, 404, "nothing")
  end
end
```

However, that will store the same key/value for every post request.  Presumably, you want to store whatever is sent in the body of the post request.  Do you know the difference between a get request and a post request?  A get request tacks data onto the end of the url, while a post request sends the data in the "body of the request", so there are different procedures for extracting the data depending on the type of the request.

What tutorial are you reading?  This tutorial: https://www.jungledisk.com/blog/2018/03/19/tutorial-a-simple-http-server-in-elixir/, shows you how to extract the data from the body of a post request.  The data in the body of a post request is just a string.  If the string is in JSON format, then you can convert the string into an elixir map using `Poison.decode!()`, which will allow you to easily extract the values associated with the keys that you are interested in.  For example:

```
  post "/storage/set" do
    {:ok, body_string, conn} = read_body(conn)
    body_map = Poison.decode!(body_string)

    IO.inspect(body_map) #This outputs to terminal window where server is running 

    message = get_in(body_map, ["message"])    
    send_resp(
      conn, 
      201,
      "Server received: #{message}\n"
    )
  end
```

Then you can use the following curl command in another terminal window to send a post request to that route:

```
$ curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "http://localhost:8085/storage/set" -d '{"message": "hello world" }'
```

(`-v` => verbose output, `-H` => request header, `-d` => data)

Now, based on what I said was wrong with your code above, you should be wondering about this line:

```
{:ok, body_string, conn} = read_body(conn)
```

That line calls:

```
read_body(conn)
```

but the variable `conn` is not assigned a value anywhere.  However, Plug invisibly creates the conn variable and assigns a value to it.

Here is a complete example using Agent to store post request data (following the tutorial I linked above):

```
simple_server
   config/
   lib/
       simple_server/
           application.ex
           router.ex
           storage.ex
   test/
```

An elixir convention is to have a directory in the `lib/` directory with the same name as your project, in this case that would be simple_server, then you give the modules you define names that reflect the directory structure.  So, in router.ex you would define a module named SimpleServer.Router and in storage.ex you would define a module named SimpleServer.Storage.  However, the `.` in a module name means nothing special to elixir, so you will not get an error if you decide to name your module `F.R.O.G.S` in the file `lib/rocks.ex`--and your code will work just fine.

router.ex:

```
defmodule SimpleServer.Router do
  use Plug.Router
  use Plug.Debugger

  require Logger

  plug(Plug.Logger, log: :debug)
  plug(:match)
  plug(:dispatch)

  get "/storage/:key" do
    resp_msg = case SimpleServer.Storage.get(key) do
      nil -> "The key #{key} doesn't exist!\n"
      val -> "The key #{key} has value #{val}.\n"
    end

    send_resp(conn, 200, resp_msg)
  end

  post "/storage/set" do
    {:ok, body_string, conn} = read_body(conn)
    body_map = Poison.decode!(body_string)

    IO.inspect(body_map) #This outputs to terminal window where server is running 

    Enum.each(
      body_map, 
      fn {key, val} -> SimpleServer.Storage.set(key,val) end
    )

    send_resp(
      conn, 
      201,
      "Server stored all key-value pairs\n"
    )
  end

  match _ do
    send_resp(conn, 404, "not found")
  end


end
```

The first thing to note in the code above is the route:

```
get "/storage/:key" do
```

That will match a path like:

```
/storage/x
```

and plug will create a variable named key and assign it the value "x", like this:

```
 key = "x"
```

Also, note that when you call a function:

```
width = 10
height = 20
show(width, height)
```

elixir looks at the function definition:

```
def show(x, y) do
  IO.puts x
  IO.puts y
end
```

and matches the function call to the def like this:

```
    show(width, height)
          |       |
          V       V
def show( x    ,  y) do
  ...
end
```

and performs the assignments:

```
 x = width
 y = height
```

Then, inside the function you can use the x and y variables.  In this line:

```
    Enum.each(
      body_map, 

      #  | | | | |
      #  V V V V V

      fn {key, val} -> SimpleServer.Storage.set(key,val) end
    )
```

Elixir will call the anonymous function passing values for `key` and `val`, like this:

```
func("x", "10")
```

Therefore, in the body of the anonymous function you can use the variables `key` and `val`:

```
SimpleServer.Storage.set(key,val)
```

because the variables `key` and `val` will already have been assigned values.

storage.ex:

```
defmodule SimpleServer.Storage do
  use Agent

  def start_link(_args) do  #<*** Note the change here
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: :tmp_storage)
  end

  def set(key, value) do
    Agent.update(
      :tmp_storage, 
      fn(map) -> Map.put_new(map, key, value) end
    )
  end

  def get(key) do
    Agent.get(
      :tmp_storage, 
      fn(map) -> Map.get(map, key) end
    )
  end

end
```

application.ex:

```
defmodule SimpleServer.Application do
  # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    # List all child processes to be supervised
    children = [
      Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.child_spec(scheme: :http, plug: SimpleServer.Router, options: [port: 8085]),

      {SimpleServer.Storage, []}
    ]

    # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: SimpleServer.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

mix.exs:

```
defmodule SimpleServer.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :simple_server,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.6",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  # Run "mix help compile.app" to learn about applications.
  def application do
    [
      extra_applications: [:logger],
      mod: {SimpleServer.Application, []}
    ]
  end


  # Run "mix help deps" to learn about dependencies.
  defp deps do
    [
        {:poison, "~> 4.0"},
        {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"}

      # {:dep_from_hexpm, "~> 0.3.0"},
      # {:dep_from_git, git: "https://github.com/elixir-lang/my_dep.git", tag: "0.1.0"},
    ]
  end
end
```

Note, if you use the dependencies and versions specified in the tutorial you will get some warnings, including the warning:

```
~/elixir_programs/simple_server$ iex -S mix
...
...

12:48:57.767 [warn]  Setting Ranch options together 
with socket options is deprecated. Please use the new
map syntax that allows specifying socket options 
separately from other options.
```

...which is an issue with Plug.  Here are the dependencies and versions that I used to get rid of all the warnings:

```
   {:poison, "~> 4.0"},
   {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"}
```

Also, when you list an application as a dependency, you no longer have to enter it in the `:extra_applications` list.  Elixir will automatically start all the applications listed as dependencies before starting your application.  See [:applications v. :extra_applications](https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2017/9/22/elixir-applications-vs-extra_applications-guide/).

Once the server has started, you can use another terminal window to send a post request with `curl` (or you can use some other program):

```
~$  curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "http://localhost:8085/storage/set" -d '{"x": "10", "y": "20" }

*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8085 (#0)
> POST /storage/set HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8085
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 23
> 
* upload completely sent off: 23 out of 23 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< server: Cowboy
< date: Fri, 30 Nov 2018 19:22:23 GMT
< content-length: 34
< cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< 
Server stored all key-value pairs
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

The `>` lines are the request, and the `<` lines are the response.  Also, check the output in the terminal window where the server is running.

```
~$  curl -v http://localhost:8085/storage/z

*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8085 (#0)
> GET /storage/z HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8085
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< server: Cowboy
< date: Fri, 30 Nov 2018 19:22:30 GMT
< content-length: 25
< cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< 
The key z doesn't exist!
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

.

```
~$  curl -v http://localhost:8085/storage/x

*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8085 (#0)
> GET /storage/x HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8085
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< server: Cowboy
< date: Fri, 30 Nov 2018 19:22:37 GMT
< content-length: 24
< cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< 
The key x has value 10.
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but the error is telling you that the `key` and `value` that are passed to the router `with` statement are not defined. Elixir thinks you are trying to call a function with those arguments because they are not "bound" to a value. That is why you are seeing `warning: variable "value" does not exist and is being expanded to "value()"`

I suppose this is not really an answer but maybe more an explanation of the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pull the key/value params out of your `%Plug.Conn{}` object (conn). The key/value variables have not yet been defined within the scope of your route. The conn object is only available because it is injected by the `post` macro provided by Plug.

I am not quite aware of what type of requests you're submitting to the router, but I'll assume it's JSON as an example. You can manually parse the body in your connection by doing something like:

```
with {:ok, raw_body} <- Plug.Conn.read_body(conn),
     {:ok, body} <- Poison.decode(raw_body) do
  key = Map.get(body, "key")
  value = map.get(body, "value")
  # ... other logic
end
```

The Plug project, however, provides a nice convenience plug for you to parse request bodies in a generic way: [Plug.Parsers](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.html).

To implement this in your router, you just have to add the plug to the top of your router (below Plug.Logger I think):

```
plug Plug.Parsers, 
  parsers: [:urlencoded, :json]
  json_decoder: Poison,
  pass: ["text/*", "application/json"]
```

The `:urlencoded` part will parse your query parameters and the `:json` part will parse the body of the request.

Then below in your route, you can get the key/value params from your `conn` object in the `:params` key like so:

```
%{params: params} = conn
key = Map.get(params, "key")
value = Map.get(params, "value")
```

Also, I should note that the best JSON decoder at the moment is [Jason](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/Jason.html) which is basically a drop-in replacement for Poison, but faster.

Anyway, reading hexdocs really helps with figuring this stuff out and the Plug project has great documentation. I think Elixir is a great language to start programming with (although it's essential to learn object-oriented paradigms as well). Happy coding!