# Is there a convention for nested modules within an empty "parent" module?

Tags: elixir

Let's say I create multiple helpers modules within an app:

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Helpers.Uri do
  @moduledoc """
  A collection of string helpers.
  """
end

defmodule MyApp.Helpers.Crypto do
  @moduledoc """
  A collection of crypto helpers.
  """
end
```

Is it a good practice to create an empty "parent" module?

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Helpers do
  @moduledoc """
  Gather all my app helpers.
  """
end
```

I guess not since using a plural for the last part of a module name seems like a wrong practice from all the code I read. But I want to be sure.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a plural module name, but there's not much reason to define an empty module. Sometimes, though, you see parent modules used as an API boundary.

Comment: The module `MyApp.Helpers` has zero relationship to the module `MyApp.Helpers.URI`.  In other words, the dots in a module name mean (almost) nothing to elixir.  See the line starting with "*An elixir convention is*"  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53560553/926143).  Module names with dots are just an adhoc namespacing convention to prevent name clashes with other module names.

Comment: Thank you @7stud :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @7stud commented, the use of dots in a namespace is merely a commonly accepted convention which is even used within [Elixir core code](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir). This is only done to easily prevent name collisions (which is reinforced by the path matching names).

Therefore **adding an empty in-the-middle module appears rather unnecessary**.

As @brett-beatty commented, **regarding the use of plural for trailing module names**, there doesn't seem to be any common practice ruling against that. If we follow the most popular [Elixir style guide](https://github.com/christopheradams/elixir_style_guide) rules, the only conventions would be to [use CamelCase](https://github.com/christopheradams/elixir_style_guide#camel-case) as well as [matching the project directories path](https://github.com/christopheradams/elixir_style_guide#module-name-nesting).

*Note: I gathered the comments to close this question.*